# Using a particular theorem, characterise abelian groups which have only finitely many elements of each order (including $\infty$)

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups, torsion-groups

This is part of **Exercise 4.3.5** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3AAbelian%20groups%2C%20OR%20content%3Afinitely%20many%20elements&p=10) and [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Babelian-groups%5D+finitely+many+elements+of+each+order+), it is new to MSE.

Here is the previous part:

[An abelian $p$-group has finitely many elements of each order iff it satisfies ${\rm min}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4226977/104041)

### The Details:

A group $G$ satisfies ${\rm min}$ if every set $S$ of subgroups of $G$ has at least one minimal element (with respect to $H\le K$ for $H,K\in S$).

A group $G$ is a $p$-group, for prime $p$, if each element of $G$ has order a power of $p$.

On page 12, *ibid.*,

> A *torsion group* (or *periodic group*) is a group all of whose elements have finite order.

### The Question.

> [Using the previous part], characterise abelian groups which have only finitely many elements of each order (including $\infty$).

### Thoughts:

I think part of the solution has to do with torsion groups. The case when the group has elements of infinite order might be handled separately.${}^\dagger$

Cheating a little, I looked through Rotman's *"An Introduction to the Theory of Groups (Fourth Edition)"* and found this:

> **Theorem 10.7 (Primary Decomposition).** Every torsion group $G$ is a direct sum of [abelian $p$-groups].

*This is something to keep in mind as a guide only. I don't think it would be constructive to cite it in a solution to the exercise (without proof).*

---

A torsion group can have infinitely many elements of a given order; for example, consider

$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\Bbb Z_2.$$

---

The question is trivial for finite groups.

---

I think I could answer this myself if I had enough time. Therefore, I would prefer hints over full solutions.

---

$\dagger$ If $g\in G$ has infinite order, then so does $g^i$ for each $i\in \Bbb N\setminus \{0\}$, since otherwise, if $\lvert g^i\rvert=n$, then $\lvert g\rvert$ divides $in$, a contradiction. Thus there cannot be finitely many elements of infinite order (other than zero of them).

---

Please help :)

Comment: The Primary Decomposition theorem is easy: just let $P$ be the set of all $p$-power elements, and notice that for any prime it is a subgroup. Then $G$ is the product of the $P$s over all primes $p$.

Comment: Moding out by the torsion and using the observation you made you can conclude the group is torsion. Any torsion abelian group is a direct sum (product/restricted product/weak product) of its $p$-parts: the proof is identical to that used in the case of finitely generated abelian groups. That reduces the problem to the $p$-parts, and you just finished [characterising the abelian $p$-groups that have only finitely many elements of any given order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226977/an-abelian-p-group-has-finitely-many-elements-of-each-order-iff-it-satisfies).

Comment: But: since there may be infinitely many primes $p$ involved, the group need not have min any more.

Comment: (An example of such a group is $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, no?)

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: Or more simply, $\oplus_{p\text{ prime}}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. ($\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ being the sum of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$). Once you have reduced to $p$-groups, you then just need to restrict to finitely many nontrivial factors.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But Q/Z is one of the groups under consideration, as it satisfies the hypothesis. So we cannot restrict to finitely many factors.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: I got a little confused and I was less than clear: if you want to describe all abelian groups that satisfy min, then you end up with "finitely many factors" (only finitely many elements of any given order, plus must be a $\pi$-group for some finite set of primes; since a torsionfree element yields an infinite descending chain of subgroups too). For the groups under consideration here, given the context in Robinson, I expect he wants to have it be described as "torsion groups whose $p$-part satisfy min, for each prime $p$".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree that that's the only obvious conclusion, but I don't like it, and can't help but wonder if there's some nice alternative that the author was driving at.